# error in post angular form parameter to node js

Tags: node.js, angular

i'm new in angular and node js
i have a multitab form in angular that in one tab i want to insert record with node js to mysql table
in html form i have this:

```
<mat-card-content fxLayout="column" [formGroup]="formGroupCaption" >
                  <mat-form-field>
                       <input matInput placeholder="caption" formControlName="caption" autocomplete="off">
                       <span *ngIf="!formGroupCaption.get('caption').valid && formGroupCaption.get('caption').touched">insert caption</span> 
                  </mat-form-field>
                 </mat-card-content>

                <mat-card-actions >
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" (click)="insert_caption()">Login</button>
                </mat-card-actions>
```

in ts file i have below:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
      this.get_data();
      this.Create_Form_Caption();
  }
   Create_Form_Caption(){
    this.formGroupCaption=new FormGroup({
      'caption':new FormControl(null,[Validators.required])
    })
  }
  insert_caption(){
    const caption=this.formGroupCaption.value.caption;
    console.log(caption);
    this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/item_create",caption).subscribe(
      (res) => {console.log(res)}
 );
```

and my js file is:

```
app.post("/item_create",(req,res)=>{

 console.log('caption is :' + req.body.params.caption);
 const insertquery="INSERT INTO captiontbl (description) VALUES ('" + req.body.params.caption + "')";
 ConnectToDB().query(insertquery,(err,result)=>{

    if (err){
        console.log("error"+err);
        res.sendStatus(500); 
        return;
    }
    res.send("inserted" + result);
    res.end();
})
```

**i recive error in nodejs:**
****Cannot read property 'caption' of undefined**
and dont return value of caption

adding that body_parser definition has massage :'bodyParser' is deprecated.
and bodyParser shown with Strikethrough:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 'req.body.params.caption' use 'req.body.caption' in the api call and check. In angular end change 'this.http.post("localhost:3000/item_create",caption)'  to 'this.http.post("localhost:3000/item_create",{caption})'.

Comment: this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/item_create",{caption})
Give this in angular side and check.